# scapy - how to define an arbitrary length enum field

Tags: python-3.x, scapy

I need to extend the IKEv2 implementation of the current [scapy](https://github.com/secdev/scapy) (scapy 2.4.0rc5) to support "configuration payload" as defined in section 3.15 of [RFC7296](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7296#page-112).

A "configuration attribute" is defined as follows:

[image: IKEv2 Configuration Attribute]

The Attribute Type is an enumerated field that I have defined as follows:

```
IKEv2_CP_attribute_types = { 
    1: "INTERNAL_IP4_ADDRESS",
    2: "INTERNAL_IP4_NETMASK",
    3: "INTERNAL_IP4_DNS",
    4: "INTERNAL_IP4_NBNS",
    6: "INTERNAL_IP4_DHCP",
    7: "APPLICATION_VERSION",
    8: "INTERNAL_IP6_ADDRESS",
    10: "INTERNAL_IP6_DNS",
    12: "INTERNAL_IP6_DHCP",
    13: "INTERNAL_IP4_SUBNET",
    14: "SUPPORTED_ATTRIBUTES",
    15: "INTERNAL_IP6_SUBNET",
    16: "MIP6_HOME_PREFIX",
    17: "INTERNAL_IP6_LINK",
    18: "INTERNAL_IP6_PREFIX",
    19: "HOME_AGENT_ADDRESS",
    20: "P_CSCF_IP4_ADDRESS",
    21: "P_CSCF_IP6_ADDRESS",
    22: "FTT_KAT",
    23: "EXTERNAL_SOURCE_IP4_NAT_INFO",
    24: "TIMEOUT_PERIOD_FOR_LIVENESS_CHECK",
    25: "INTERNAL_DNS_DOMAIN",
    26: "INTERNAL_DNSSEC_TA",
    16389: "P_CSCF_IP4_ADDRESS_ALT",    # widely used instead of 20 
    16390: "P_CSCF_IP6_ADDRESS_ALT"     # widely used instead of 21
}
```

but what is the appropriate scapy field for "Attribute Type"?

It should be something like:

```
class CP_Attribute(IKEv2_class):
    name = "IKEv2 CP Attribute"
    fields_desc = [
        ByteEnumField("attr_type",None,IKEv2_CP_attribute_types),
        PacketField("load", "", Raw)
        ]
```

but "ByteEnumField" is single byte, and "Attribute Type" is a 15 bit field.(I can use a 16 bit instead of 15, since R bit must be set to 0)

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer looking deeply into other protocols with similar fields inside scapy:

```
IKEv2_CP_types = {
    1: "CFG_REQUEST",
    2: "CFG_REPLY",
    3: "CFG_SET",
    4: "CFG_ACK"
}

IKEv2_CP_attribute_types = { 
    1: "INTERNAL_IP4_ADDRESS",
    2: "INTERNAL_IP4_NETMASK",
    3: "INTERNAL_IP4_DNS",
    4: "INTERNAL_IP4_NBNS",
    6: "INTERNAL_IP4_DHCP",
    7: "APPLICATION_VERSION",
    8: "INTERNAL_IP6_ADDRESS",
    10: "INTERNAL_IP6_DNS",
    12: "INTERNAL_IP6_DHCP",
    13: "INTERNAL_IP4_SUBNET",
    14: "SUPPORTED_ATTRIBUTES",
    15: "INTERNAL_IP6_SUBNET",
    16: "MIP6_HOME_PREFIX",
    17: "INTERNAL_IP6_LINK",
    18: "INTERNAL_IP6_PREFIX",
    19: "HOME_AGENT_ADDRESS",
    20: "P_CSCF_IP4_ADDRESS",
    21: "P_CSCF_IP6_ADDRESS",
    22: "FTT_KAT",
    23: "EXTERNAL_SOURCE_IP4_NAT_INFO",
    24: "TIMEOUT_PERIOD_FOR_LIVENESS_CHECK",
    25: "INTERNAL_DNS_DOMAIN",
    26: "INTERNAL_DNSSEC_TA",
    16389: "P_CSCF_IP4_ADDRESS_ALT",    # widely used instead of 20 
    16390: "P_CSCF_IP6_ADDRESS_ALT"     # widely used instead of 21
}

class CP_Attribute(IKEv2_class):
    name = "IKEv2 Proposal"
    fields_desc = [
        BitField("R", 0, 1),
        BitEnumField("attr_type",1, 15, IKEv2_CP_attribute_types)
        FieldLenField("length",None,"value","H"),
        PacketField("value", "", Raw)
        ]

class IKEv2_payload_CP(IKEv2_class):
    name = "IKEv2 CP"
    overload_fields = { IKEv2: { "next_payload":47 }}
    fields_desc = [
        ByteEnumField("next_payload",None,IKEv2_payload_type),
        ByteField("res",0),
        FieldLenField("length",None,"attribs","H", adjust=lambda pkt,x:x+8),
        ByteEnumField("cfg_type",None,IKEv2_CP_types),
        X3BytesField("res2",0),
        PacketLenField("attribs",conf.raw_layer(),CP_Attribute,length_from=lambda x:x.length-4),
        ]
```

I tested it in an IKE_AUTH message and it does generate valid configuration payload. 
Since scapy is incredibly flexible, I am pretty sure that there are other ways to do the same more efficiently. So I welcome proposals before I contribute this to scapy in a couple of weeks.